# Ms Access Connect to Java

Tags: java, database

I'm currently developing a JAVA project and I want it to be connected to MS Access.

```
try {
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ= C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Downloads\\questions.accdb", "", "");

System.out.println("Connection Succesfull");
} 
catch (Exception e) {
System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
```

i added the ojdbc6 library to my project library but its not working im getting the error "Got an exception! sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" im running a 64bit JVM but the access file is 32bit engine is that matter? thanks

ERROR

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at access.main(access.java:6)
```

Comment: Can you print the full message? `e.printStackTrace(System.err)`

Comment: i updated my post thanks for the reply

Comment: ojdbc6.jar has nothing to do with connecting to Access. It is the driver for Oracle.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ahhh so thats why. its now clear to me.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i want to use UCanAccess how will i include that?

Comment: See the linked duplicate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc